# Travis-CI passing a build

Tags: ruby, github, rspec, travis-ci

I just started ruby testing using `rspec` a couple of days ago and am enjoying it.
I noticed travis-ci's badge in most of the repos on GitHub, and thought of giving it a try. How does travis-ci actually work? I mean what does it take travis-ci to get a status of `build passing`.

I have asked travis-ci to monitor one of my GitHub repos, and it always fails a build, returning a state of Errored. Any thoughts on this: https://travis-ci.org/swaroopsm/doattend

Comment: Have you found that you can get the build failure details by clicking on the job, e.g. for 14.3: https://travis-ci.org/swaroopsm/doattend/jobs/11128014  ? In this case, `cannot load "webmock/rspec"`, which points to perhaps a missing dependency in your gemspec = `spec.add_development_dependency "webmock"`

Answer (score 0):

Reposting [Neil Slater's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686912/travis-ci-passing-a-build#comment27527651_18686912) since the original poster said it solved their issue.

> Have you found that you can get the build failure details by clicking on the job, e.g. for 14.3: [travis-ci.org/swaroopsm/doattend/jobs/11128014](http://travis-ci.org/swaroopsm/doattend/jobs/11128014) ? In this case, `cannot load "webmock/rspec"`, which points to perhaps a missing dependency in your gemspec = `spec.add_development_dependency "webmock"`